# Howto perform OpenStack upgrade from Essex to Folsom on juju maas

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

Following the tutorial on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure i've set up a small OpenStack environment on juju and MAAS. One problem is that it only runs essex. To me it seems strange since grizzly is coming soon.

Watching this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcwqvAFBQVg&t=18m47s seeing how easy Shuttleworth updated his essex to folsom i tried that approach, but that just made config errors. So how is the approach - how can i update it easily? And which charms to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found a solution. For the interested i will bring my solution here:

To update from Essex to Folsom we want to use the Ubuntu Cloud Archive. That unfortunatly is not possible at the moment by default in MaaS. It has been reported as a bug. I realized this after debugging the hooks in the nova-cloud-controller charm, which is one of the charms giving errors when updating.

To enable cloud repositories on MaaS do the following:

Go edit `/etc/squid-deb-proxy/mirror_dstdomain.acl`,
line 14:
and change the line

```
archive.canonical.com
```

To

```
.archive.canonical.com
```

This solves the problem and changing openstack-orign on each charm from distro to cloud:precise-folsom will update from essex to folsom!